# find the value of pi till 50 digits

Tags: java, math, pi

I want to calculate the value of PI till 50 digits.

How to do this in java for 50 decimal places?

Comment: The `22/7` approximation is precise to 2 decimal places only, why do you need 50 places?

Comment: Following up on what atzz wrote, just to make sure you take notice: 22/7 is only pi to 2 decimal places. Your code thus prints out 22/7, and your question can be interepreted as "how do I print 22/7 to 50 decimal places?".

Comment: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Pi#Computation_in_the_computer_age

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class PiReCalc {
  public static final int N = 1000; // # of terms
   public static void main(String[] args) {
  BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);      // final sum
  BigDecimal term = new BigDecimal(0);           // term without sign
  BigDecimal sign = new BigDecimal(1.0);     // sign on each term

  BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal(1.0);
  BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal(2.0);

  for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
     BigDecimal count = new BigDecimal(k); 
     //term = 1.0/(2.0*k + 1.0);
     BigDecimal temp1 = two.multiply(count);
     BigDecimal temp2 = temp1.add(one);
     term = one.divide(temp2,50,BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);

     //sum = sum + sign*term;
     BigDecimal temp3 = sign.multiply(term);
     sum = sum.add(temp3);

     sign = sign.negate();
  }
  BigDecimal pi = new BigDecimal(0);
  BigDecimal four = new BigDecimal(4);
  pi = sum.multiply(four);

  System.out.println("Calculated pi (approx., " + N + " terms and 50 Decimal Places): " + pi);
  System.out.println("Actual pi: " + Math.PI);
   }
}
```

The output is

**Calculated pi (approx., 1000 terms and 50 Decimal Places): 3.14059265383979292596359650286939597045138933077984**
**Actual pi: 3.141592653589793**

Comment: Why is the third digit a `0` instead of a `1`?.. :S

Answer (score 3):

You cant do that with default data types, as you need for 50 digits: 50 / log(2) * log(10) = 166 bits. Here BigDecimal is one type you could use instead. But you should have in mind, that 22/7 is just an approximation of pi, and to get it right for 50 digits you need much better formula (e.g. Monte-Carlo method, taylor series, ...).

Comment: It will take a while for the Monte-Carlo method to converge to 50 decimal places.  See http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/node38.html for a few more practical ways of computing it.

Comment: thanks @flolo. as said i used BigDecimal and it worked out fine. i have added the code below.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a double variable and instead should use something that has a greater precision. Look into the `BigDecimal` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the break through paper of Bailey, Borwein and Plouffe: http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/pihex/p123.pdf

In the meantime, even faster formulas (following the same principles) were found: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellard%27s_formula

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty implementation of Bellard's formula bigPi(200,2000) is good for over 500 decimal places in 75ms.

```
public static BigDecimal bigPi(int max,int digits) {
    BigDecimal num2power6 = new BigDecimal(64);
    BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++ ) {
        BigDecimal tmp;
        BigDecimal term ; 
        BigDecimal divisor;
        term = new BigDecimal(-32); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(4*i+1); 
        tmp =  term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
        term = new BigDecimal(-1); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(4*i+3); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        term = new BigDecimal(256); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(10*i+1); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        term = new BigDecimal(-64); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(10*i+3); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        term = new BigDecimal(-4); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(10*i+5); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        term = new BigDecimal(-4); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(10*i+7); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        term = new BigDecimal(1); 
        divisor = new BigDecimal(10*i+9); 
        tmp = tmp.add(term.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
        int s = ((1-((i&1)<<1)));
        divisor = new BigDecimal(2); 
        divisor = divisor.pow(10*i).multiply(new BigDecimal(s));
        sum = sum.add(tmp.divide(divisor, digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR));
    }
    sum = sum.divide(num2power6,digits, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR);
    return sum;

}
```